# Is 노트북 only used for the computer notebook?

Tags: vocabulary

Is 노트북 only used for the computer form of notebook, or do some use it for paper based notebooks? If so, is it considered Konglish?

Comment: I would not consider it Konglish. I know some people use that word broadly for all English loan words in Korean, but I only use it for English-inspired (i.e. not real English) words in Korean. For example, "skinship" or "grand open."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'노트북' is only used for laptops, '공책' is used for notebooks made out of paper.

Comment: "노트" can also be referred to paper notebooks